# PySimpleGui error code after running script

Tags: python, pycharm, pysimplegui

I have a simple python script , witch when closing popup-window gives error-message.
I have tried the different ways in PySimpleGui to write the correct code but it doesen´t work.
So  I have a popup window with four choices; 1 monitor, 2 monitor, extend monitors and quit.
They all do what I want them to do, but if I close the window ( X ) without making a choice , I get an error.
I am a beginner.
here is the code:

```
**import os
import subprocess
os.chdir("C:/windows/system32/")
current_dir = r"C:/windows/system32/"
import PySimpleGUI as sg
sg.theme('Bluepurple')  # Add a touch of color
layout = [ [sg.Text('Chose monitor')],
[sg.Button('1 monitor'), sg.Button('2 monitor'), sg.Button('3 extend'), sg.Button('4 quit') ]]
window = sg.Window('Chose monitor', layout,)
while True:
    event, values = window.Read()
    if event == '1 monitor':
     subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(current_dir, "Displayswitch.exe /internal"))
    elif event == '2 monitor':
     subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(current_dir, "Displayswitch.exe /external"))
    elif event == '3 extend':
     subprocess.Popen(os.path.join(current_dir, "Displayswitch.exe /extend"))
    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == '4 quit'):
     break
    window.close()****
 
here is the error message:
[error][1]
```

Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Regards:
Goesta

Comment: This line is wrong `if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == '4 quit'):`, although it wouldn't cause your error.  You want `if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, "4 quit"):`.

Comment: Also, is the `window.close()` line actually shifted all the way to the left, as it should be?  You don't want that to be part of the loop.

Comment: Found what was wrong. One misspelled word. Now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

In your GUI, there're five elements, one `sg.Text` and 4 `sg.Button`, and also five kind of events may happen, 4 buttons and one window close button, so you need to handle all the events in your event loop.

In general, value of `event` will be the key of event or element.
Here, key not defined in your `sg.Button`, so default key is the first argument `button_text` of `sg.Button`.

Another event is the close button of window, it will be `sg.WIN_CLOSED`.

```py
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == key1:               # '1 monitor'
        do_job1()
    elif event == key2:             # '2 monitor'
        do_job2()
    elif event == key3:             # '3 extend'
        do_job3()
    elif event == key4:             # '4 quit'
        do_job4()
    elif event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:    # Window close button event
        break

window.close()
```

Here, it will do the same thing for event `'4 quit'` and window close event `sg.WIN_CLOSED`, so we handle them in same case and break event loop to close window.

```py
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == '1 monitor':
        do_job1()
    elif event == '2 monitor':
        do_job2()
    elif event == '3 extend':
        do_job3()
    elif event in ('4 quit', sg.WIN_CLOSED):
        break

window.close()
```

#### Update

1. Root cause for message `Trying to read a closed window`

It means your window already closed by `window.closed()` or destroied when close button of window clicked. That's why statement here to break while loop to call `window.close()` and no more `window.read()`.

```py
while True:

    event, values = window.read()
    ...
    elif event in ('4 quit', sg.WIN_CLOSED):   # Window close button event
        break

window.close()
```

2. For message `You have tried 100 times to read a closed window`, it clearly show that you didn't break while loop and call `window.read()` again and again. Check your event while loop to confirm everything is fine.

Comment: Thanx for the input .I tried all of them . Sorry to say I still get the error:

Comment: What the error ? show full error message.

Comment: error: "Trying to read a closed window" You have tried 100 times to read a closed window". "You need to add a check event ==WIN_CLOSED"

Is there a way to just disable the (X)-button? Goesta

Comment: Update in answer.